# ILNumerics: no ilpanel

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

Dear stackoverflow community,

i'm absolutly new in programming in c#, especially using ILNumerics.

The Problem is: i cannot get an ilpanel. The installation of ILNumerics into the project works without problems, ILNumerics.3.3.3.0 and IlNumericsNative3.3.0 are sucessfully installed and added. Doing the first test - solving an equation as a consoleApplication - works also.

But trying the 'Quickstart - getting Visual' wont work. There is no ilpanel in the toolbox. Right-clicking and choosing 'Choose Items...' and selecting the IlNumrics.dll shows the message 'There are no Components in 'C:...\packages\ILNumerics.3.3.3.0\lib\ILNumerics.dll' that can be placed on the toolbox.' I dont know what to do then.

If someone could help me, i would be very very happy! Normally, im only programming in Matlab...

Best regards
Christian

Comment: Solved the problem.. I worked consequently in an folder called 'c#tutorial'. the c# compiler had no problem with it, using ilnumerics an the functions was no problem also, but to create an ilPanel...  next time I'm coming with a more qualified problem, i promise! thanks for your replys!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project targets at least .Net framework 4.0.

The toolbox will prevent controls to show up, if the corresponding assemblys framework version does not match the target version of the project. ILNumerics targets .Net version 4 or newer. Thats why its controls are only visible to projects targeting at least version 4 also.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My projects target is .Net framework 4.5, and I tried also other versions. Visual Studio 2012 is what I'm using.

Comment: Try resetting the toolbox (right click -> Reset) and retry to choose the item again. Also, make sure, to have a Windows Forms form (and not WPF!).

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks guys! I had the same issue could not import the ilpanel in the tolbox, but removing "#" from the folder path name where my project was stored solved the problem!